# Issues with reading .dat file in R

Tags: r, read.table, read.csv

I have big problems in reading this file:

https://gofile.io/?c=0aID8j

It was a .csv when I read it in the first time:

```
files = list.files(pattern=".csv")
df = read.csv(files[1],header = TRUE, sep=";")
```

Then I saved it like this (this is the file from the link)

```
file_name <- paste ("df.dat", col="", sep="")
write.table(df, file_name, row.names=TRUE, col.names=TRUE)
```

And now I fail to read it again. This is what I tried already:

```
files = list.files(pattern="df")
df = read.table(files[1],header = TRUE, sep=",")
df = read.table(files[1],header = TRUE, sep=";")
df = read.table(files[1],header = TRUE, sep="")
df = read.table(files[1],header = TRUE, sep=".")
df = read.table(files[1],header = TRUE)

df = read.csv(files[1],header = TRUE, sep=";")
df = read.csv(files[1],header = TRUE, sep=",")
df = read.csv(files[1],header = TRUE, sep="")
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: I downloaded your file, but it seems to be a invalid csv file. The header and the content column count doesn't match.

Comment: `read.table("AUG-2017-NO2.dat", skip=1)`skip=1 because you have less header columns then columns. This works for me, but you have to get your header correct. I think it's easier to `colnames` it afterwards. Something like: `colnames(df) <- c("index", "date", "time"....)`

Comment: Ok, so I made a mistake when I saved it? Do you know how to correct it?

Comment: @mischva11 Thanks! That is already a big help. Its not in the same format than it was before, but at least its working!

Comment: the Problem is: we don't know what's your original file. I think you made a mistake while saving it, so you changed the format. For example you added an index and the date and time split up, so you got not enough column headers. If you are still satisfied with this, i still can add my commentar as answer.

You also can just changed the ending .dat to .csv and you see it's not identical to your original csv. Also you can set `row.names=1` in `read.table` for getting rid of the index

Comment: Thank you! I think I got the problem. My original file was a .csv with the time as a factor. I converted it with: library(lubridate)
df[,1] = lubridate::dmy_hm(df[,1]) into a readable time and cut out the year 2017. So I think the time is the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there occurred a problem while transforming the csv to dat.
You can read a .dat file which is in csv format with `read_table`

So in you case: `read.table("AUG-2017-NO2.dat", skip=1, row.names=1)`

You have to skip a row since your column headers are less then columns. So you can try to save your csv correctly (which you fixed in the commentary; issue was the time stamps) or you change columns names afterwards with:

`colnames(df) <- c("Date", "Time", "BourgesPlatz", "Karlstraße", "Königsplatz", "LfU")`

The `header=TRUE` argument did not work in your examples, since you had less header names then columns